# Whenever I am adding ContentNegotiatingViewResolver bean, All my other jsp pages stops working

Tags: spring-mvc

Whenever I am adding ContentNegotiatingViewResolver bean, All my other jsp pages stops working, I get this error - HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator

This is my servlet-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                        <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/> 
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>         
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```